# Remove focus rectangle on a UserControl

Tags: wpf, focus, focusvisualstyle

I have a WPF UserControl with Focusable="True". It's the only focusable control in the window.

Whenever the user presses Tab or Alt (and especially when they Alt+Tab to another application), my UserControl acquires a dotted-line border, aka focus rectangle. The focus rectangle then stays there until the window is closed.

How can I prevent my UserControl from ever displaying this focus rectangle?

#### Edit

It turns out the focus rectangle wasn't actually being displayed by my UserControl. My Focusable UserControl contained another UserControl that, in turn, contained an ItemsControl, and the ItemsControl is what was showing the focus rectangle.

When I added FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" to the ItemsControl, the focus rectangle went away.

Comment: Are you sure it's the UserControl and not an element inside it which acquires the rectangle? I couldn't duplicate this for a pure UserControl with quick testing.

Comment: Interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: Mikko, thanks for putting me on the right track -- see edit.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you want to not display the focus rectangle in any case you could set the FocusVisualStyle to null.

```
<MyControl FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
```

Comment: I assume that would go on the UserControl that has Focusable="True". If so, it had no effect. It still shows the dotted-line rectangle as soon as I press Alt.

Comment: Never mind. It worked when I found the right control to put it on. See edit.

Comment: I've been trying to work out how to do this for ages.  Thanks